# Web Services: Rolling back a committed Transaction

Tags: web-services, transactions, apache-camel

Im new to webservices.
Im sending a webservice request to cxf endpoint through a camel route marked "transacted" and the response is got.
In the same transaction route, next statement throws an exception so that my Exception handler rollsback the transaction.

I can find other things in my transaction rolledback, except my webservice request response since its already commited.

Is there a way of rolling back commited webservice request?
Or is there a way of sending a rollback last webservice request ??

Please help, Stuck for 3 days on same...

Answer (score 0):

Just make another webservice to undone everything done by the first webservice and call it in `.onException()` routine

Comment: Thanks for the suggesion. I have kept this idea as last option since, the task of creating another webservice for all the existing methods is tedious. If im able to send another request of auto rollback to same webservice with some unique id or something, it would be easy. But found no hint. Im still wondering how can this be achieved in an automatic way..

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such thing as transactions for web services. You can find information on wikipedia such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensating_transaction